# How can I convert DIA_User[] to List<DIA_User>

Tags: c#, linq

I used `wcf` service to work directly to database.

And the result I got as this format: `DIA_User[]`

I can use linq for this as select, find,... but I dont know how to convert to `List<DIA_User>`

Please advise.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 5):

Just use `ToList()` method, which is an extension method on `IEnumerable<>`

```
DIA_User[] x = new DIA_User[] {};
List<DIA_User> y = x.ToList();
```

Answer (score 4):

```
List<DIA_USER> users = new List<DIA_USER>(diaUserArray);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var arrayUser = new DIA_User[]();
var listUsers = arrayUser.ToList();
```

BTW, you can configure your WCF service to send `Lists` instead of `Arrays`.